# What exactly is Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've looked up plenty of information on Rails, but I still can't say I'm quite sure of *what it is*. If I'm developing a web app, what functionality would I get that I couldn't from html/js/php? Would every project benefit from rails, or do you need a certain goal in mind?

Comment: It's just Ruby programming language running on rails, which makes it really fast compared not running it on rails.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby on Rails is a [web application framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework). Technically there isn't anything that Rails can do that HTML/JS/PHP can do.  The point of Rails it to make developing websites easier, faster, and hopefully more maintainable.  If you are familiar with PHP, then Rails is somewhat equivalent to [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/), [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/) or [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/).

I'd recommend trying out some of these tutorials if you haven't already.

- [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) - you won't even have to setup rails on your machine
- [Ruby on Rails tutorial book](http://railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)
- [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) - for once you get more into it

Comment: developing faster perhaps, but the production deployment is way slower than just sticking to pure html/js and nodeJs for example

Answer (score 4):

Ruby on Rails is a web framework built for programmer productivity and happiness. It's built on top of the Ruby language which means you get access to all the cool libraries ("gems") other people have written such as file upload libraries and ones that interact with web services such as AWS.

You use HTML and JavaScript with it just like you would in every other web framework out there. The difference? It's not built on top of a hack of a language such as PHP. Good Ruby code is elegant and very readable, and you will find this out in your usage of the framework.

The Getting Started guide explains it very well: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by happiness? Is this any sort of new age movement?

Answer (score 1):

What it is is a framework. It's a set of APIs, a toolkit if you may, to build web applications.

Ruby is a programming language like Python, Perl, C, C++, Java, C#, PHP etc. It's closer to Perl and Python than to other due to its interpretive nature (a scripting language if you may).

RubyOnRails is a framework built on top of Ruby to build web apps. Arguably like Servlets is used to build web apps on Java or .Net is used on C#, or Django on Python or CakePHP on PHP etc. It's an amalgamation of APIs, code generation tools, testing code etc put together.

It's popular because of it's elegance, it's choice of following conventions over configuration (you write less config code or glue code). Once you get the hang of it, there is less ceremony involved before you get from idea in your head to working production application with RubyOnRails (popularly referred to as Rails).